# IIS handling of 204 responses

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

We're migrating a .NET web application from Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8.5 to Windows Server 2019 running IIS 10.0.

We have some code which sends a `PATCH` request from one bounded context into an API in another bounded context. The response to this request is `204 (No Content)`.

The request is sent through a common method which attempts to parse the body for successful responses (*i.e.*, 2xx codes).

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    // ...
}
```

Maybe this needs changed but that's not what puzzles me.

When responded from Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.5 the parsing of a `204 (No Content)` response using the above code caused no problems.

When responded from Windows Server 2019 / IIS 10.0 the parsing of the same response using the same code causes an exception.

> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.

Why?

The code is running on the same version of .NET Framework on both servers.

Does IIS handle `204 (No Content)` responses differently?

Comment: it seems not about your code. It seems the server you're hitting either can't handle the load, or is intentionally dropping your requests because you're hitting it too hard.

Comment: Not only is it our own server, it's the same server from which the request is sent - I mentioned in the OP "sends a PATCH request from one bounded context into an API in another bounded context". The server is also a development/staging server which only a colleague and I are using, so it's not about load handling.

Comment: You can also use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.